# how can I convert a Grid object to a Graphics object?

Tags: plotting, export, output-formatting

I have a figure (which is by combining different plots) that I generated using `Grid[]`. The problem is, I want to specify the `ImageSize` of this final figure.  I am unable to do it in `Grid[]`. Therefore, I wanted to convert this `Grid[]` object to `Graphics[]` object so that I can save it as a `PDF` of desired `ImageSize`.

**Note**: I tried to save the output of `Grid[]` as `PDF` using `Export[]`. It works fine. However, when I set `ImageSize` in `Export[]`, it seems to be ignored.

I tried

```
i=First@ImportString[ExportString[figure, "PDF"]];
```

But even this seems to lose clarity but this gives crispier image than `Rasterize`

`Magnify[]` seems to do what I want even if It doesn't convert the figure to
graphics, I can change the resolution by trial and error. Not the best
way to do it but gets the job done.

Comment: Have you tried `Rasterize`? http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rasterize.html

Comment: that works but not as good as exporting the grid[] directly to output pdf which had size of 877X353 but much clearer than output of Rasterize[] which I had set to an ImageSize of 1000. I played around with RasterSize increasing it all the way to 15000. But doesn't seem to get better. Do you know what causes this loss of clarity?

Comment: I'm pretty new to the function too, was trying to use it to determine the height of a column. Nevertheless, are you using ImageSize as a parameter for your expert or your Rasterize? Try it for Rasterize if you've yet to do so.

Comment: Yes, I tried both ImageSize and ImageResolution. Neither seems to work in my case. The issue is that the output from Grid[] seems to capture all the information whereas Rasterize and ExportString seem to lose some. I don't know how to prevent that.

Comment: Why not use `GraphicsGrid` instead of `Grid`, it has a `ImageSize` option to set the overall size of the whole graphics grid.

Comment: Because GraphicsGrid resizes the individual components at its own will. I don't know how to prevent that.

Comment: How about Magnify?

Answer (score 2):

I am still confused about this question. I am posting this just to understand better what is wrong again with using `GraphicsGrid` or `Magnify` as was suggested above? Here is just an example. Why this does not work?  It is also easy to use `ItemSize` to control the size of each entry in the `GraphicsGrid` if needed.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Manipulate[
 s = Which[method == "GraphicsGrid",
   GraphicsGrid[tbl, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {.5, .5},ImageSize -> n],
   method == "Magnify", Magnify[Grid[tbl, Frame -> All], n/500]
   ],

 {{n, 300, "how big?"}, 200, 1000, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{method, "GraphicsGrid"}, {"Magnify", "GraphicsGrid"}},
 Button["Export to PDF", Export["s.pdf", s]],
 Initialization :>
  (
   tbl = Table[ListPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10],Joined->True,ImageSize->100], {3}, {3}]
   )
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Magnify does work. With GraphicsGrid, I tried to play around with ItemSize. But I could not get it to do what I want. One main difference from your example is, I have one item spanning the whole row and two other items spanning the next row. The alignment is a problem. I cannot align each element differently as in case of grid.