# Export grid of figures (not GraphicsGrid) to pdf

Tags: graphics, export, grid-layouts

I am trying to prepare a grid of `DensityPlots` (or actually `ArrayPlots`  [because they are faster](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109650/why-is-listcontourplot-so-slow)). The plots should have color scale bars attached, which I do using the `Row` command because [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132951/38410) because `GraphicsRow` and `GraphicsGrid` really don't let you align the objects nicely (also see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35193/ugly-output-when-combining-2-plots-with-graphicsrow)).

Now the question is: If `plot1`, `plot2`, ..., `plotn` are each plots generated by combining two `DensityPlot`s using `Row`, like

```
plot1=Row[subplot1,colorbar1]
```

how can I show these plots a grid and export that grid to pdf, without linebreaks in the middle of a row (see also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29674/how-can-i-convert-a-grid-object-to-a-graphics-object) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437681/exporting-a-row-of-graphics-objects-broken-in-mma8)).

Basically, what I tried is

```
allPlots = Grid[Transpose[{{plot1,plot2}, {plot3, plot4}}];
Export["figure.pdf", allPlots];
```

Now the color bars are in a separate row and not next to their plots, as intended.

When I output the result in the notebook, everything looks fine. There, the only problem is that working with the notebook becomes very laggy (scrolling, typing, etc.), but that is not really part of the question.

One comment: I realized that the plots, created by `Row`, are no graphics objects. Maybe it would be a solution to convert each plot into a graphics object, but how? See also [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29674/how-can-i-convert-a-grid-object-to-a-graphics-object).

**Edit:**

To illustrate the problem, here is a code to reproduce the issue:

```
(* Function to generate the color bar legend *)

customBarLegend[zmin_, zmax_, label_, colorFunction_: Automatic] := 
 Module[{},
  Show[ArrayPlot[
    Table[{zmax + zmin - y}, {y, zmin, zmax, (zmax - zmin)/100}],
    ColorFunction -> colorFunction,
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {zmin, zmax}},
    Frame -> True,
    FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, label}},
    FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}},
    PlotRangePadding -> 0,
    AspectRatio -> 20,
    Axes -> False],
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {zmin, zmax}}]]

(* Function to convert a regular (ugly) BarLegend into a custom bar
legend that has the same height as the plot. *)

convertBarLegend[plot_, imPad_, barPad_, size_] := 
 Module[{zmin, zmax, zlabel, colorFunction, bar},
  {zmin, zmax} = (List @@ (List @@ plot)[[2]][[1]])[[1]][[2]];
  zlabel = LegendLabel /. (List @@ (List @@ plot)[[2]][[1]])[[3]];
  colorFunction = (List @@ (List @@ plot)[[2]][[1]])[[1]][[1]];
  bar = customBarLegend[zmin, zmax, zlabel, colorFunction];
  Row[{Show[(List @@ plot)[[1]], ImageSize -> {Automatic, size}, 
     ImagePadding -> imPad], 
    Show[bar, ImageSize -> {Automatic, size}, ImagePadding -> barPad]}]
  ]

(* Test data *)

data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, x + y}, {x, 0, 50}, {y, 0, 50}], 1];

 (* Plot the test data as ArrayPlot because ListDensityPlot increases 
the output file size by a factor 20 *)

uglyplot = Block[{data2, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin, zmax},
   data2 = 
    Reverse[Transpose[
      Partition[data[[All, 3]], 
       Length[DeleteDuplicates[data[[All, 2]]]]]]];
   xmin = Min[data[[All, 1]]];
   xmax = Max[data[[All, 1]]];
   ymin = Min[data[[All, 2]]];
   ymax = Max[data[[All, 2]]];
   zmin = Min[data[[All, 3]]];
   zmax = Max[data[[All, 3]]];
   ArrayPlot[data2,
    ColorFunction -> 
     ColorData[{"M10DefaultDensityGradient", {zmin, zmax}}],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    PlotRangePadding -> None,
    FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}},
    DataRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}},
    PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "z"]]];
imPad = {{50, 7}, {60, 
   10}}; (*{{left,right},{bottom,top}}*)
barPad = {{1, 100}, 
  imPad[[2]]};(* bottom and top should be the same as imPad. *)
plot =
  convertBarLegend[uglyplot, imPad, barPad, 300];

(* Arrange the plots in a grid *)
plotgrid = 
 Grid[{{plot, plot}, {plot, plot}}]

(* Export *)
Export["plotgrid.pdf", plotgrid];
Export["plotgrid.png", plotgrid];
```

The png file looks fine:

[image: png]

but the pdf is messed up:

[image: pdf]

Comment: Related: [(65211)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65211/spanning-centering-elements-with-grid-graphicsgrid-when-theres-a-non-equal-numb).

Comment: True, but the solution there (using a combination of `Row` and `Column`) leads to the same effect. I believe that the core of the problem is that `Row` sometimes introduces linebreaks. Maybe the question actually is: how can I force a `Row` object to be monolithic, i.e., to forbid line breaks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to prevent line breaks in the exported image, you can use `LineBreakWithin -> False` (here I'm using `ExportString` instead of `Export` just for convenience):

```
row = Row@Table[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], 10];
First@ImportString[ExportString[row, "PDF"], "PDF"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
First@ImportString[ExportString[Style[row, LineBreakWithin -> False], "PDF"], "PDF"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for!